# Is there anyway to change the font in a MapIcon element?

Tags: uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I have a UWP application where I am placing MapIcon elements on a MapControl. I use a custom image and specify the text, but would like to make the font slightly larger. Is there anyway to change the font size for MapIcons? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can. You could try creating your own design by templating the `ItemTemplate` of `MapItemsControl`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with RS2, you can customize the styling of the map including MapIcon using the styling API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/elements-of-map-style-sheet
Font size is one of the things that can be customized.

Comment: Very nice. I think the property is called `labelScale`.